# sourcetree - git :I want a committed in head

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am a newbie with git. I have commited some changes. I made a mistake and I didn't commit it in any branch and it is in head. I would like to commit this in a branch.

If I run
git reflog show
I can see that it is in head(7) with a code 15a3e43

If I run this, then I'm in the last element of head
git chechout HEAD^

if I run
git chechout -b branchA
branchA is created and the last is moved to this branch

I have tried to get to head(7)
git checkout HEAD@{1}
git chechout 15a3e43
and no way. I would like to move the commit of head(7) to a branch.

Thanks,
Joan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a specific commit to another branch, you can use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

1. Move to that other branch
2. `git cherry-pick <commit_hash>`

A new commit with the content of `<commit_hash>` will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 15a3e43 is the hash of the last commit you made, you can merge it (and previous commits) into a branch with:

```
git checkout branchname
git merge 15a3e43
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the following commit graph

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H master
```

And you want commit D-H to go to a different branch. What you do is the following:

```
git branch newBranch
git reset --hard C

A - B - C master
         \
          \
           D - E - F - G - H newbranch
```

#### Keep in mind, that this is harmful if you have already pushed everything you miss-commited.